# How to show live results on terminal from a shell script?

Tags: terminal, programming, text-user-interface

How can I write a shell script that shows the results in real time?

Something like the [`top`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_(software)) command that updates the results after some fixed intervals of time.

[image]

Comment: probably using a `curses` interface... but I think this is more heavily a programming question and belongs on SO

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would help if you were a lot more specific about what you are trying to do.

Here is an *extremely* simplistic example:

```
while true
do
    clear
    date
    sleep 1
done
```

Answer (score 13):

you can use the [watch(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch) command to run your script at regular intervals:

```
watch -n 1 myscript.sh
```

This will run `myscript.sh` every 1 second clearing the screen between each run and with a timestamp in the corner. You can use the `-d` option and it will even highlight differences in the output per run.

Comment: I was just thinking of how to answer it using watch.

Comment: I don't have `watch`. Could you be more specific? What OS?

Answer (score 2):

Most of that data is generally exposed in the /proc virtual file-system primitives. Each process has an entry in /proc in a directory called the PID. So /proc/5437 would have the primitives for the 5437 process. Reading the primitives there and parsing appropriately would yet you close to what top does.

Top actually works by calling specific function calls that extract this information directly from the kernel instead of pulling it from files. To do the same from bash you'd have to either pull it from the /proc virtual file system, or extract it out of other calls such as to `ps`.

As for real-time, that isn't quite doable at the level of detail top provides. You can slice time fine enough that it appears to be real-time, but you will still be getting time-slices.

Answer (score 2):

Erm, in case you're looking at `top` output for a longer time, and not just to check if a program is doing fine, I suggest using [htop](http://htop.sourceforge.net/).

It give's you a lot of real time information and is easier to control and manage.

You can change the layout of the output, such as bar graphs and columns.

Comment: I believe he is asking how to write an app that polls at regular intervals not about top or htop specifically.

Answer (score 1):

`top` uses [Curses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29) and reads the `/proc` file system

Comment: Except on systems that don't have `/proc`. Another way to get the information is sysctl(8)/sysctl(3).